# Plotting netCDF4 weather data in python - confused about shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf4

I have been trying to plot the Great Lakes Wave netCDF4 data that is available here:

https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/wave/prod/glwu.20220108/glwu.glwu.t01z.nc

I am confused about how this data is organized. The netCDF4 is setup like this:

```
longitude
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 longitude(node)
    units: degree_east
    long_name: longitude
    standard_name: longitude
    valid_min: -180.0
    valid_max: 360.0
    axis: X
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (253010,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
latitude
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 latitude(node)
    units: degree_north
    long_name: latitude
    standard_name: latitude
    valid_min: -90.0
    valid_max: 180.0
    axis: Y
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (253010,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
time
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
    long_name: julian day (UT)
    standard_name: time
    units: days since 1990-01-01 00:00:00
    conventions: relative julian days with decimal part (as parts of the day )
    axis: T
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (150,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
tri
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int32 tri(element, noel)
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (418488, 3)
filling on, default _FillValue of -2147483647 used
MAPSTA
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int16 MAPSTA(node)
    long_name: status map
    standard_name: status map
    units: 1
    valid_min: -32
    valid_max: 32
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (253010,)
filling on, default _FillValue of -32767 used
uwnd
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 uwnd(time, node)
    long_name: eastward_wind
    standard_name: eastward_wind
    globwave_name: eastward_wind
    units: m s-1
    _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
    scale_factor: 1.0
    add_offset: 0.0
    valid_min: -990
    valid_max: 990
    comment: wind=sqrt(U10**2+V10**2)
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (150, 253010)
filling on
vwnd
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 vwnd(time, node)
    long_name: northward_wind
    standard_name: northward_wind
    globwave_name: northward_wind
    units: m s-1
    _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
    scale_factor: 1.0
    add_offset: 0.0
    valid_min: -990
    valid_max: 990
    comment: wind=sqrt(U10**2+V10**2)
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (150, 253010)
filling on
hs
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 hs(time, node)
    long_name: significant height of wind and swell waves
    standard_name: sea_surface_wave_significant_height
    globwave_name: significant_wave_height
    units: m
    _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
    scale_factor: 1.0
    add_offset: 0.0
    valid_min: 0
    valid_max: 32000
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (150, 253010)
filling on
```

And the dimensions:

```
{'level': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'level', size = 1,
 'node': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'node', size = 253010,
 'element': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'element', size = 418488,
 'time': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'> (unlimited): name = 'time', size = 150,
 'noel': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'noel', size = 3}
```

Any tutorials I have followed always suggest doing something like this (I am interested in the wave height):

```
lat = ds.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = ds.variables['longitude'][:]
wh = ds.variables['hs'][0,:]. # first time interval
```

And then doing a plt.countourf plot. I was able to get this to work following tutorials with example data, but in those cases the element variables always had a lat and lon dimension included.

I don't understand how this dataset works, as the element shape (wave height in this case, but they are all the same), once I pick one of the time dimensions, is the same as the lat and lon shapes. How does it make sense to plot something like that? In any examples I have seen the element itself would include lat and long dimensions as well.

I'm okay with the plotting itself, just wondering if anyone could point me in a general direction or resource of how to make sense of a file like this? Does it have to do with the "tri" variable? There is a lot of data in there it looks like.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a bunch of nodes and they each have a lat and Lon as well as wave height as a function of time.  If you want to contour this you should use tricontour or grid the dataset.

Comment: Thanks so much! - Makes sense now.